# How to call a getter inside a computed properties

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I am using the modules mode of the `store` and in my `projects.js` inside my store folder I have:

```
export const getters = {
   loadedProjects(state) {
       return state.loadedProjects;
   }
}
```

now in my computed how should I call it?
I’m trying like that:

```
computed: {
   loadedProjects() {
     return this.$store.getters.projects.loadedProjects;
   },
 }
```

but I get this error:

```
Cannot read property ‘loadedProjects’ of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, if you are using the **modules mode** you can call your getters like that (in your case): `this.$store.getters['projects/loadedProjects'];`

So try to change your computed like that:

```
computed: {
   loadedProjects() {
     return this.$store.getters['projects/loadedProjects'];
   },
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your getter like this:

```
loadedProjects() {
    return this.$store.getters['projects/loadedProjects'];
}
```

$store.getters['moduleName/getterName']